# How to set a different border line of every single point or serie in Highcharts scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors, scatter-plot, point

I want to make a border around point in Scatter plot in Highcharts.

I found only how to change a marker, but it works only for hover state:

```
marker: {
    lineColor: "red"
}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/10a9xddg/1/

Is there a way, how to set a border color for a point in a "normal" state or set it for a points of certain serie?

Comment: Thanks for a possible workaround, but I need to set a point border only.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/10a9xddg/19/ ?

Comment: Oh my god. There is a lineWidth property default value set to 0. Thank you very much, ewolden!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lineWidth property, which is 0 by default. This property has to be set to some value, then the border line is visible.

Thanks to ewolden.